# Principled BSDf roughness greater than 1

Tags: shaders

Some values of the Principled BSDf like specular accepts inputs that are greater than 1, because some materials for example for diamonds the specular reflectivity would be greater than 1.
Obviously this also applies to parameters like clercoat, sheen and anistropy, with accompanying visual changes of the material.
For some other parameters like for exmple metallic values over 1 are simply clamped internally, such that there are no visual changes in the material.
Now for some reason the roughness parameters accepts values over 1 and which has a visible brightening effect on the material.
But is this physically based like is in the case with specular and what would that connection with physics be or is this simply an oversight by the developers?

Comment: I'd say an oversight, values over 1 violate energy conservation imho :)). I remember this issue being mentioned some years ago, just probably was never amended.